# failed to resolve: com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:21.+

Tags: android, gradle, android-service

After changing  minSdkVersion 10 to  minSdkVersion 11 in build.gradle file. i am getting failed to resolve: com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:21.+ error

Error(30,13) Install Repository and Sync Project 
             Show in File 
             Show in project structure dialog

Comment: I have the same problem

Comment: I've deleted this line : compile 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:21.+' from build.gradle and now it builds successfully

Comment: I also did the same, it's build successfully

Comment: Actually for me it showed a 'Install dependencies and sync' button in the Messages window. This installed missing components and fixed the problem.